# accessing camera on androidemulator

Tags: android, camera, emulation

I am trying to use laptop camera in emulator.I have provided camera support to my emulator, But when I click on camera application on emulator I am getting white screen on android 2.3.3 and something like black boxes in android 2.1. Whenever I start virtual machines I am asked with camera permissions.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. you need to test it on real device.

Comment: this is not possible. you cannot access it in emulator. but u can do in tablet emulators.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to "simulate camera in the android emulator using the webcam" except by extensively modifying the Android firmware

It is possible for 3.1 and more

check this... [webcam in emulator](http://www.tomgibara.com/android/camera-source)